# Python foreach equivalent

Tags: python, foreach

I am diving into Python and I have a question about foreach iteration. I am new to Python and I have some experience in C#. So I am wondering, if there is some equivalent function in Python for iteration all over all items in my collection, e.g.

```
pets = ['cat', 'dog', 'fish']
marks = [ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

or something like this.

Answer (score 476, accepted):

Sure. A for loop.

```
for f in pets:
    print f
```

Comment: What about if I must know the index/key also?

Comment: Then you would use enumerate.  `for k,v in enumerate(pets):`  etc.

Comment: This construct is unfortunately not intrinsic to collections but instead  external to them. The result is two-fold:  (1) it can not be chained ( 2) it requires two lines in idiomatic python.  Python does not support a true `foreach` on collections directly. or chaining in general. An example would have been  ``myList.foreach( a => print(a)).map( lambda x:  x*2)`.

Comment: The `f` persists (leaks) beyond (after) the loop. Worth mentioning, I think. Not relevant specifically with your answer, but since it's the accepted answer, I did [think this is worth mentioning].

Answer (score 47):

Like this:

```
for pet in pets :
  print(pet)
```

In fact, Python *only* has foreach style `for` loops.

Answer (score 31):

Its also interesting to observe this

To iterate over the indices of a sequence, you can combine `range()` and `len()` as follows:

```
a = ['Mary', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'lamb']
for i in range(len(a)):
  print(i, a[i])
```

output

```
0 Mary
1 had
2 a
3 little
4 lamb
```

**Edit#1: Alternate way:**

When looping through a sequence, the position index and corresponding value can be retrieved at the same
time using the `enumerate()` function.

```
for i, v in enumerate(['tic', 'tac', 'toe']):
  print(i, v)
```

output

```
0 tic
1 tac
2 toe
```

Answer (score 14):

For an updated answer you can build a `forEach` function in Python easily:

```py
def forEach(list, function):
    for i, v in enumerate(list):
        function(v, i, list)
```

You could also adapt this to `map`, `reduce`, `filter`, and any other array functions from other languages or precedence you'd want to bring over. For loops are fast enough, but the boiler plate is longer than `forEach` or the other functions. You could also extend list to have these functions with a local pointer to a class so you could call them directly on lists as well.

Comment: Can you include usage please?

Answer (score 6):

While the answers above are valid, if you are iterating over a dict {key:value} it this is the approach I like to use:

```
for key, value in Dictionary.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Therefore, if I wanted to do something like stringify all keys and values in my dictionary, I would do this:

```
stringified_dictionary = {}
for key, value in Dictionary.items():
    stringified_dictionary.update({str(key): str(value)})
return stringified_dictionary
```

This avoids any mutation issues when applying this type of iteration, which can cause erratic behavior (sometimes) in my experience.

Comment: A more readable alternative to this is to iterate over a `copy` of the dictionary, so you can manipulate the dictionary during iteration (though your copy will be of all keys and values prior to any modification) -- like `for key, value in Dictionary.copy().items()`

Comment: You mean `stringified_dictionary.items()` right?

Answer (score 5):

The `foreach` construct is unfortunately not intrinsic to collections but instead  external to them. The result is two-fold:

- it can not be chained
- it requires two lines in idiomatic python.

Python does not support a true `foreach` on collections directly. An example would be

```
myList.foreach( a => print(a)).map( lambda x:  x*2) # python can't do this..
```

But python does not support it.  Partial fixes to this and other missing functionals features in python are provided by various third party libraries including one that I helped author:  see https://pypi.org/project/infixpy/

Comment: Showing a code fragment of an unsupported feature is hardly useful, somewhat misleading.

Comment: I provided description before and after the snippet saying this is what *could* be provided (but is not). That is not uncommon to do. The usefulness is to be *clear* about what a true _foreach_ construct is.

Answer (score 4):

For a dict we can use a for loop to iterate through the `index`, `key` and `value`:

```
dictionary = {'a': 0, 'z': 25}
for index, (key, value) in enumerate(dictionary.items()):
     ## Code here ##
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
def smallest_missing_positive_integer(A):
A.sort()
N = len(A)

now = A[0]
for i in range(1, N, 1):
  next = A[i]
  
  #check if there is no gap between 2 numbers and if positive
  # "now + 1" is the "gap"
  if (next > now + 1):
    if now + 1 > 0:
      return now + 1 #return the gap
  now = next
    
return max(1, A[N-1] + 1) #if there is no positive number returns 1, otherwise the end of A+1
```